# mat-label not aligning with the outline border in mat-form-field

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, mat-card

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bflTh.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY8la.png)

if you see the card the label is overlapping with the border.
outline is on right side coming
i want the default behaviour of mat-form-field but its not working

after removing formgroup from that it is coming fine but still the behaviour is not same.
i want the formgroup with mat-form-field